# How to create a method that will return a custom object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a method that will return an instance of a custom class in JavaScript.

**What I have:**

The model class:

```
function ProductModel() {
    this.ProductName = "";
    this.ProductId = "";    
}
```

Method that should create and populate an object of the above class and return:

```
function GetNewProductModel() {
    var newProduct = new ProductModel();

    newProduct.ProductName =  $("#textProductName").val();
    newProduct.ProductId = "";

    return newProduct;
}
```

The way it's called:

```
function PreviewProduct() {
        var productModelForPreview = GetNewProductModel();
        console.log(productModelForPreview);
}
```

**What I see:**

In the console I see this:

```
function productModelForPreview()
```

**What I can't seem to do:**

I expect to get a ProductModel whose properties can be accessed like any other object.

Surely I am missing the fundamentals here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/57ud2ooo/

Comment: How are you calling this function PreviewProduct()

Comment: Mohit that will be called on a button click

Comment: Change `console.log(productModelForPreview);` to `console.log(productModelForPreview.ProductName );` You'll see it do act likes an object.

Comment: I don't see the problem here.

Comment: fuyushimoya it say's undefined

Comment: @Codehelp It is undefined because you are not getting value of $("#textProductName").val().If you are able to access productModelForPreview.ProductName It means you are also able to access productModelForPreview as an object

Comment: @Mohit the value does get assigned, I can see that in console

Comment: @Codehelp This is beacuse your javascript is executing before the dom loads

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. I tested on Chrome (43), FF (31) and IE (9) and it just works as expected. By the way I recommand you to

- Change browser tool
- Take a quick look at some [OOP Javascript site](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. We can assume that you have exposed only the problematic part of it. Though, nothing in that part of your code contains what make  it fails.
`productModelForPreview` is a function when you execute and it should be an object (an instance of ProductModel).

We can't help you but you can search in your code the assignment that makes `productModelForPreview` a function instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly fine. Your observed behavior will happen if you write

```
var productModelForPreview = GetNewProductModel;
```

but here it's fine.